# HapiJS global path prefix

Tags: node.js, url-routing, hapi.js

I'm writing an API on HapiJS, and wondering how to get a global prefix.  For example, all requests should be made to:

```
https://api.mysite.com/v0/...
```

So I'd like to configure `v0` as a global prefix.  The docs ([here](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/routing)) don't seem to mention it -- is there a good way to do this in HapiJS?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you put your API routing logic inside a [Hapi plugin](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/plugins), say `./api.js`:

```
exports.register = function (server, options, next) {

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/hello',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            reply('World');
        }
    });

    next();

};

exports.register.attributes = {
    name: 'api',
    version: '0.0.0'
};
```

You register the plugin with a server and pass an optional route prefix, which will be prepended to all your routes inside the plugin:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');

var server = new Hapi.Server()
server.connection({
    port: 3000
});

server.register({
    register: require('./api.js')
}, {
    routes: {
        prefix: '/v0'
    }
},
function(err) {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.start(function() {
        console.log('Server running on', server.info.uri)
    })

});
```

You can verify this works by starting the server and visiting `http://localhost:3000/v0/hello`.

Comment: I can't seem to get this method working.  I was able to set it directly with `server.realm.modifiers.route.prefix = '/v0'`, but not by nesting options as you show.  Are you sure your approach works?

Comment: Yes, I just tested it with Hapi 8. This prefix option is only available when registering a single plugin though. So if you're registering multiple plugins, it won't work.

Comment: @MattHarrison It's probably a good idea to update your answer with the multiple-plugin disclaimer :)

Comment: This doesn't work with multiple plugins.. which 80% of hapi stacks will have.

Comment: @olive_tree you can specify the prefix option per-plugin now http://hapijs.com/api#serverregisterplugins-options-callback. Or just use Glue

Comment: @MattHarrison i am specifying for a plugin- still doesn't work.  How would glue fix it?

Answer (score 10):

I was able to get it working for all routes with

```
var server = new Hapi.Server()
...
server.realm.modifiers.route.prefix = '/v0'
server.route(...)
```

Answer (score 5):

[Matt Harrisson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28028699/1806019) is the *hapi* way to do it using plugins.

Alternatively if you don't want to create a plugin just to add a prefix, you can *by hand*, add the prefix to all your routes.

For instance I went for something like this:

```
  var PREFIX = '/v0';
  var routes = [/* array with all your root */];

  var prefixize = function (route) {  route.path = PREFIX + route.path;return route; }
  server.route(routes.map(prefixize));
```

Good point is that with something like this your can perform `express`-like mounting. ex:

```
 var prefixize = function (prefix, route) {  route.path = prefix + route.path;return route; }

server.route(adminRoutes.map(prefixize.bind({}, "/admin"))); //currying.
server.route(apiRoutes.map(prefixize.bind({}, "/api")));
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as Matt Harrisson's answer doesn't work for multiple plugins- which most people will have.

Answer (score 2):

For Hapi 19, 20 ... you can simply modify the route with **map** path before you register it.

```
// Example route
const routes = [
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/test',
        handler: function (request) {
            return {
                status: 'success'
                };
            }
    }
];

// transform /test -> /api/test
routes.map((r) => {
    r.path = `/api${r.path}`;
    return null;
});


// Register
server.route([
    ...routes
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can always start your index.js like this

```
if (!global.PREFIX) {
  global.PREFIX = '/v0';
}
```

this way everywhere inside your code you'll have access to PREFIX

that's how you can access to PREFIX

`console.log(PREFIX);` or `var name = PREFIX+ "_somename";`

Answer (score 1):

I’m late to this party but this came up in search results.. FWIW, I'm using this, built off of [AdrieanKhisbe’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29166520). It allows for setting multiple global prefixes and using sub-route prefixes (similar to how Django urls are laid out). Here is a sample with multiple route.js files and api route versions (the route handlers moved out for clarity):

**/departments/routes.js**

```
const { getDepartments, getDepartmentById } = require('./handlers');

module.exports = [
  { method: 'GET', path: '', handler: getDepartments },
  { method: 'GET', path: '/{id}', handler: getDepartmentById }
];
```

**/users/routes.js**

```
const { getUsersV1, getUserByIdV1, getUsersV2, getUserByIdV2 } = require('./handlers');

const userRoutesV1 = [
  { method: 'GET', path: '', handler: getUsersV1 },
  { method: 'GET', path: '/{id}', handler: getUserByIdV1 }
];

const userRoutesV2 = [
  { method: 'GET', path: '', handler: getUsersV2 },
  { method: 'GET', path: '/{id}', handler: getUserByIdV2 }
];

module.exports = { userRoutesV1, userRoutesV2 };
```

**index.js**

```
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');
const departmentRoutes = require('./departments/routes');
const { userRoutesV1, userRoutesV2 } = require('./users/routes');

const init = async () => {
  const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
    host: 'localhost',
  });

  const allRoutes = [];

  const v1 = '/api/v1/';
  const v2 = '/api/v2/';

  const prefixer = (routeArray, apiPrefix, subRoutePrefix) => {
    routeArray.map(route => {
      route.path = `${apiPrefix}${subRoutePrefix}${route.path}`;
      allRoutes.push(route);
    });
  };

  prefixer(departmentRoutes, v1, 'departments');
  prefixer(userRoutesV1, v1, 'users');
  prefixer(userRoutesV2, v2, 'users');

  server.route(allRoutes);

  await server.start();
  console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  console.log(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [hapi-auto-route](https://github.com/sitrakary/hapi-auto-route). This plugin automaticaly register your routes from a directory

```js
// Directory structure
// 
// node_modules/
// routes/
//  home.js
// server.js
// package.json

// routes/home.js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: (request, h) => 'Hello';
}

// server.js
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');

const server = Hapi.Server({
  port: 3000,
  host: 'localhost'
});

const init = async () => {
    await server.register(require('hapi-auto-route'));
    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server is running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) => {
  console.log(error);
  process.exit();
});

init()
```

and add prefix to it:

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I implemented mine

I created a helper function that takes an Array of `Hapi.ServerRoute` then map through it and concatenate the prefix then return the array.

The snippets are in Typescript so if you're using JavaScript just strip off the types

```js
// Helper function
export function routerGroup (namespace: string, routes: Hapi.ServerRoute[]) {
  return routes.map(r => {
    r.path = namespace + r.path
    return r
  })
}
```

```js
// Routes declarations

export default routerGroup('/v1/api', [
    {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/login',
        options: {
            validate: {
                payload: Joi.object({
                    email: Joi.string().required().email(),
                    password: Joi.string().required().min(8).max(30)
                })
            },
            auth: false
        },
        handler: Authentication.adminLogin
    }
] as Hapi.ServerRoute[]
)
```

```js
// Register routes to Hapi server
server.route(
  [
    ...v1Routes,
    ...
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server.realm.modifiers.route.prefix = '/api/v2'
await server.route(yourroutes);
```

This should work fine, however if you want to be able to parse all the routes automatically from your routes directory/file [Hapi Router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-router). You would be able to do something like this which will save you a lot of time.

```
await server.register({
    plugin: HapiRouter,
    options: {
        routes: "./src/routes/product-routes.js",
    },
}, {
    routes: {
        prefix: "/api/v1"
    }
});
```

Your route file should look like this.

```
export default [{
    method: "GET",
    path: "/products",
    options: {
        tags: ["api", "Products"],
        description: "Get All Products",
    },
    handler: () => {...}
}]
```