# Add prefix to all api's in hapi

Tags: node.js, server, hapi.js, hapi

I have this code written in `index.js` file. My api's are running successfully on the **`/`** path. Now I need add a prefix to all my api's. I don't want to add one by one by editing each file. I need to do in one go.

```
composer((err, server) => {
  if (err) throw err

  server.initialize((errInit) => {
    if (err) throw errInit
    server.register({
      register: require('hapi-cron'),
      routes: { prefix: '/api' },
      options: {
        jobs: []
      }  
    }, (err) => {
      server.start(() => {
        const env = process.env.NODE_ENV
        const msg = `${env} server started at ${server.info.uri}`
        server.log(['server', 'info'], msg)
        if (_.includes(['sandbox', 'production'], env)) {
        }
      })    
    })   
  })
})
```

How Can I do this? Thank in advance!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HapiJS global path prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871324/hapijs-global-path-prefix)

Comment: @Ankh Thank you for the reply but that didn't work for me

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show what you've tried and what hasn't worked

Comment: @Ankh I have updated my question. please have a look

Comment: `const server = Hapi.server({});
server.realm.modifiers.route.prefix = '/api'`

Comment: If you use glue then it will be easy to handle such requirements easily. Where you can register your plugins and specific prefix according to plugins.